# Php multiple isset. Any other way to make this work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a form where i have to insert in my dB several values from a checkbox btn group into different columns. I also have to insert two different values depending if the btn is checked or not.
I made it work in the following way, but is there another way for this became more simple? It´s a lot of issets :). 
Thanks for your time. 
Best regards!
NM

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

// Create connection
include ('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['fixvalue']) && ($_POST['fixvalue'] == 0)) { 
    $fixvalue= "fixvalue";
} else { 
    $fixvalue= 0;
};

if(isset($_POST['frtvalue']) && ($_POST['frtvalue'] == 0)) { 
    $valueone= "valueone";
} else { 
    $valueone= 0;
};

if(isset($_POST['secvalue']) && ($_POST['secvalue'] == 0)) { 
    $valuetwo= "valuetwo";
} else { 
    $valuetwo= 0;
};  

if(isset($_POST['thevalue']) && ($_POST['thevalue'] == 0)) { 
    $valuethree= "valuethree";
} else { 
    $valuethree= 0;
};

if(isset($_POST['fovalue']) && ($_POST['fovalue'] == 0)) { 
    $valuefour= "valuefour";
} else { 
    $valuefour= 0;
};  

if(isset($_POST['fitvalue']) && ($_POST['fitvalue'] == 0)) { 
    $valuefive= "valuefive";
} else { 
    $valuefive= 0;
};

$sql = "INSERT INTO values(fixvalue,valueone,valuetwo,
                            valuethree,valuefour,valuefive)
                VALUES('".$fixvalue."','".$valueone."','".$valuetwo."',
                        '".$valuethree."','".$valuefour."','".$valuefive."')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo'<button class="btn btn-success" style="left:400px;bottom:20px;width:200px;">Sucess</button>';
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record OK');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>"     $con->error."');</script>";
}

$con->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use a loop.

Comment: _Small Note_ You dont need to add semi colon after the last `}` of an if like this `};`

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I already try a foreach but the values were always entered whether the button was selected or not. I'm kind of a newbie in this....

Comment: @RiggsFolly yea i know... this is a kind of a first draft... but tks :)

Comment: You do realise that checkboxes are only sent from the browser to PHP if they are actually checked right. So all you need to do is test if they exist in $_POST and that means they have been checked

Comment: that`s ok.... but the if the ckbox are not ckded no data is sent to the dB... the field gets empty and i need it to be 1 or 0 for example.... Already try with a type hidden btn but no results achieved .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fixvalue"> Checkbox<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valueone"> Checkbox 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valuetwo"> Checkbox 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valuethree"> Checkbox 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valuefour"> Checkbox 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valuefive"> Checkbox 5<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$fields = [
    'fixvalue' => 0,
    'valueone' => 0,
    'valuetwo' => 0,
    'valuethree' => 0,
    'valuefour' => 0,
    'valuefive' => 0
];

if($_POST['submit']){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($key !== 'submit') {
            $fields[$key] = $key;
        }
    }

    extract($fields);
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (fixvalue, valueone, valuetwo, valuethree, valuefour, valuefive) VALUES(:fixvalue, :valueone, :valuetwo, :valuethree, :valuefour, :valuefive)");
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $sql->bindValue(':'.$key, $$value);
    }
    $sql->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: Well... tks @edward... but doesn't work here... keeps reporting Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in.... . Already change to bind_param for mysqli and still nothing...

Comment: @NunoMarques Sorry, I had `echo` in there before.I removed it, please try again.

Comment: It´s working... still passing null values but that's fine :) tks a lot :) best regards

Comment: @NunoMarques No problem! Please +1 and accept the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$checks = array(
    'fixvalue',
    'frtvalue',
    'secvalue',
    'thevalue',
    'fovalue',
    'fitvalue'
);
$data = array();
foreach( $checks as $value){
    $data[$value] = isset($_POST[$value]) && $_POST[$value] != '' ? $_POST[$value] : 0;
}
```

Than use `$data['frtvalue']` etc in a prepared sql statement